# How to block all applications from accessing a connection in Windows 7 firewall?

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, windows-firewall

I consider myself quite tech-savy but this one gives me real pain.

I've connected to VPN through PPTP and I'm attempting to set up firewall rules to block any application from using it. Essentially, I want this working on a white-list basis, and leave my primary local connection for general use. Local connection is listed as private network and VPN as public. So in Windows Firewall, advanced settings, I set up one rule for inbound and one for outbound connections, both using similar settings:

- all programs
- all ports & protocols
- all IP addresses
- **block** connection
- public profile
- from "Advanced" tab in rule editing window, I mark "remote access" interfaces.

This doesn't work - my applications can still connect through VPN. In fact, any combination of profile and interfaces settings either don't do anything, or blocks both local and VPN connection. What should I do in order to get this done?

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to have this much control with Just Windows Firewall

Comment: i'm not great with the w7 firewall but you say local connection is listed as private and VPN as public. Is it possible to make local connection a custom profile and VPN a custom profile?  By the way, in the windows 7 firewall I think public means like you're telling it you're in a coffee shop i.e. it makes it very restrictive, and isn't a VPN very secure.. so maybe that's funny unless you want VPN very limited which maybe you do. but anyhow, perhaps you can have 2 custom profiles one for VPN one for local network.

Comment: As far as i know, Windows 7 doesn't have notion of custom profiles. At the time of connecting to new network, it lets user choose between the 3 (domain, local and public).

Comment: @Red perhaps this is somewhat like it?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956291/how-can-i-add-a-widows-firewall-rule-with-a-custom-group-name    but it looks painfully complicated if like me one doesn't know powershell. It mentions a custom group name

Answer (score 0):

The windows firewall is configured to only enforce incoming rules by default. If you just wrote rules for incoming and outgoing, only the incoming connections will be filtered. You would need to enable the enforcement of outgoing rules by setting the firewall to block outgoing connections which enables the "whitelist mode" you ask for.